# Mapping Routes inside Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to map your routes inside of Controllers?  I prefer having my routes defined near my controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

If your motivation is to co-locate routing rules with associated controller actions then I don't believe that is possible in Rails. The controller actions are executed post-routing so the ability to direct any routing behavior (such as it is) in the controller layer is limited to `redirect_to` which is just syntactic sugar for HTTP's "302 moved". Hardly a satisfactory routing strategy.

[Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) middleware ([within Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#rack-integration)) or the [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) framework more tightly couples routing and actions in code. Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Please hve a look my code .
 First dont define anything about your controller in rount.rb .

Then if your enter in browser "http://localhost:3000/users/my_action" .

Then write a following code in your controller .

Class UsersController < ....

def my_action

if request.get?
        somrthing your code ......
   end

if request.post?
        something your code ......
   end

end

end